# Rails 7: Update HTML element after ActiveJob API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 7.0 application. On page load, I'm making multiple API calls to a third party service to retrieve information to display on the page, which slows the page load time down. To alleviate this, I added an ActiveJob class that performs the API call and adds this to my background job processor. The page load time is much faster and I can see the jobs being executed in the background.

```
@derivatives.each { |d| CallLastPriceJob.perform_later(d.id) }
```

**My question is, how do I get the API information updated on page?**

In the ActiveJob class, I'm updating the instance's attribute with the API data.

```
@position.last_price = option.first["lastPrice"].to_f
```

I tried adding the `after_perform` callback in the ActiveJob class to send the updated instance to the model.

```
after_perform do |job|
  Holding.notify_last_price_processed(@position)
end
```

I assume I need to use Turbo Frames or Streams but I'm not sure since I'm new to Rails 7. I tried using the `broadcasts_to` method in `Holding.notify_last_price_processed` but it wasn't working as expected. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The `after_perform` callback in `CallLastPriceJob` is sending the `position` back to the model correctly.

As suggested by Les in the comments below, I added `<%= turbo_stream_from current_user, :positions %>` to my view. I gave each `<tr>` row a unique ID using the `dom_id` helper method. Each row is being rendered using a partial `shared/portfolio_positions`.

In the `Holding.notify_last_price_processed` method I'm using the `broadcast_replace_to` method.

```
Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_replace_to [user, :positions], target: "holding_#{position.id}", partial: "shared/portfolio_positions", locals: { position: position }
```

In my delayed_job log I can see the partial being rendered and ActionCable broadcasting

```
Rendered shared/_portfolio_positions.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 409)

[ActionCable] Broadcasting to Z2lkOi8vdGhldGFmbG93L1VzZXIvMQ:positions: "<turbo-stream action=\"replace\" target=\"holding_7513\"><template><tr class=\"border-t border-gray-300 text-sm\" id=\"holding_7513\">\n  <td class=\"whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-4 pr-3 sm:pl-6\">\n    <div class=\"inline\">TEST</div>\n    <div class=\"inline\"></div>\n  </td>\n  <td cl...

Performed CallLastPriceJob (Job ID: 20f8a4de-c6b8-473e-8b49-db66c87d845b) from DelayedJob(default) in 153.72ms
```

It appears the stream name is the same as what's being displayed in my server log.

```
Turbo::StreamsChannel is streaming from Z2lkOi8vdGhldGFmbG93L1VzZXIvMQ:positions
```

**...but the contents on the webpage aren't updating...**

**EDIT 2:**

I ran across this issue https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/48 related to updating table elements with Turbo Streams, but I tested with the workaround that was suggested and in addition, changed all elements to `<div>`s and it still isn't updating the page contents.

Again, I verify that in my delayed_job log file I can see the ActionCable broadcast message and everything appears to be connected correctly. The only thing I can't see is the cable messages in dev tools.

Comment: on your page (to which you wish to broadcast) you need to be sure the turbo js is loaded, and you need to invoke the turbo stream helper `<%= turbo_stream_from 'api_updates' %> or whatever you wish to name the stream. This name should match the `broadcast_to`.

Comment: So I'm trying to target multiple cells within an existing table. Does the turbo_stream_from method still apply?

Comment: turbo-stream is the mechanism to deliver the updated content to the web page. When it arrives at the web page, you can append-to, or replace a single element, so you would need to replace a table, a row, or a cell

Comment: @LesNightingill I updated my original post, definitely seems to be getting closer.. Any ideas?

Comment: If you can see the turbo-stream update message arriving at the web page using dev tools, then it seems that the js to update the target element is not loaded on the page

Comment: It should be loaded. I have `import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"` in the `javascript/application.js` file.

Comment: do you see the turbo stream message being delivered to the live page (look in dev tools)?

Comment: Doesn't look like it - I just see the subscribe and confirm subscription messages under `cable` on the network tab.

Comment: so you DO see the turbo update send from the server (look in the log) but you do NOT see the message received by the page (dev tools) is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I don't know, maybe the page is not subscribed to the socket with the same name that the server is broadcasting to. That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: I thought of that too, but when I check the server log and the delayed_job log it appears the names are the same.

`16:21:08 web.1  | Turbo::StreamsChannel is streaming from Z2lkOi8vdGhldGFmbG93L1VzZXIvMQ:positions`

`[ActionCable] Broadcasting to Z2lkOi8vdGhldGFmbG93L1VzZXIvMQ:positions`

Comment: out of ideas, sorry!

Comment: Should the signed stream name in the `cable` messages on the dev tools network tab be the same as `Z2lkOi8vdGhldGFmbG93L1VzZXIvMQ:positions`?

`{"channel":"Turbo::StreamsChannel","signed_stream_name":"IloybGtPaTh2ZEdobGRHRm1iRzkzTDFWelpYSXZNUTpwb3NpdGlvbnMi--94cb8573629131b30d460874b437a15766a7b2cd0b8053af918c6d1718337b1e"}`

Comment: I don't know the answer to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out and get it working, after making a few changes to my code.

- I added the `last_price` attribute to my model via migration instead of having it as a virtual attribute.
- I used the `broadcast_update_later_to` method instead of `broadcast_replace_later_to`.
- I used `[user, "positions"]` instead of `user, "positions"` for the stream name in the Model and in View.

After making these changes the contents on the page started updating.

**Final setup**

Controller:

```
@derivatives.each { |d| CallLastPriceJob.perform_later(d.id) }
```

Job:

```
after_perform do |job|
  Holding.notify_last_price_processed(@position)
end
```

Model:

```
Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_update_later_to [user, "positions"], target: "holding_#{position.id}", partial: "shared/portfolio_positions", locals: { position: position }
```

Index view:

```
<%= turbo_stream_from [current_user, "positions"] %>
```

Partial:

```
<tr class="border-t border-gray-300 text-sm" is="turbo-frame" id="<%= dom_id(position) %>">...</tr>
```